# How to create a series of buttons in JavaScript which can be clicked to do different versions of the same function?

Tags: javascript, html, django, button, django-forms

I am making a website with Django to provide students with a spelling test which they fill out and then receive a mark out of 10.
The students cannot be allowed to see the words so I have given them a series of sound bytes using the function 'speak()', only when I press the buttons they all say the same thing because I don't know how to parse the individual data to the function to tell it which spelling to "speak".

I know that the reason why it isn't working is because I'm parsing "sBite.id" to the speak() function, and sBite.id will always be the same value. I just don't know what value I should parse in order to send the correct spelling to the function

Here is the relevant JS code:

```
function speak(word){
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(usedWords[word]);
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

usedWords=[];  

function load(played, mistake, score){
  alert(mistake)
  var x =["ball","racket","apple","cheese","find","any","new",
          "display","please","happy","plead","pleat","aple","bple","cple"];
  var step;
  var spellList = document.getElementById("spellList");
  if(listlen < 10){
    for(step = 0;step < 10;step++){
      li = document.createElement("li");
      sBite = document.createElement("button");
      rand = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];
      if(usedWords.includes(rand)){
        step = step - 1;
        continue;
      }
      else{
        usedWords.push(rand);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rand));
        li.id = "spelling";
        spellList.appendChild(li);
        var testy = usedWords[step];
        sBite.setAttribute("onClick","speak(sbite.id)");
        sBite.type="button";
        sBite.id=step;
        sBite.textContent=sBite.id;
        spellList.appendChild(sBite);
        listlen++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out! 
Using this.id I am able to call the ID of each button in the list which all correspond to which number button they are. 
This means that I can send this to the 'speak()' function along with the list of words in the spelling test and return the correct sound bite.

```
function speak(words, id){
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(words[id]);
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}


function load(played, mistake, score){
  var x =["ball","racket","apple","cheese","find","any","new",
          "display","please","happy","plead","pleat","aple","bple","cple"];
  var step;
  var spellList = document.getElementById("spellList");

  if(listlen < 10){
    for(step = 0;step < 9;step++){
      li = document.createElement("li");
      li.id = "spelling";
      li.style.display = "none";
      sBite = document.createElement("button");
      sBite.type="button";
      sBite.id=step;
      sBite.setAttribute("onClick","speak(usedWords, this.id)");
      sBite.className = "spellButtons";
      rand = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];
      if(usedWords.includes(rand)){
        step = step - 1;
        continue;
      }
      else{
        usedWords.push(rand);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rand));
        spellList.appendChild(li)
        sBite.textContent="Word " + (step + 1);
        spellList.appendChild(sBite);
        listlen++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `addEventListener` to attach the click callback, and wrap your function call in a function so it only gets evaluated when the button is clicked and not when the callback is registered.

Replace this line:

```
sBite.setAttribute("onClick","speak(sbite.id)");
```

by this:

```
sBite.addEventListener("click", () => speak(sbite.id));
```

Comment: Hi jo_va, thanks for the speedy answer but unfortunately it doesn't seem like that has worked. I'm changing that line and the buttons are not doing anything, whereas otherwise they do return the last spelling in the list.

Comment: @Lucas Peters-Murphy, could retry ? I made a mistake and updated my answer

Comment: Hmm, alas, still not working. I can show some more code if that would be helpful? I'm retrying the original code each time so I know that the issue isn't something else...

Comment: Ah @jo_va so I changed it slightly just to make the syntax right ('sBite' instead of 'sbite') and it is doing something now, unfortunately that thing is the same as it was originally doing, i.e outputting the end value of sBite.id.